# How to instantiate generic class and call a method

Tags: java, generics, switch-statement

Right now I have 4 classes which have common method to be called depending on the case as given in below example.

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
Class1 class2 = new Class2();
Class1 class3 = new Class3();
Class1 class4 = new Class4();

MyEnum enum = MyEnum.valueOf(getString()); //getString() will return String "c1" or "c2" or ....

switch(s)
{
case c1 :
class1.add();
break;
case c2 :
class2.add();
break;
case c3 :
class3.add();
break;
case c4 :
class4.add();
break;
}
```

since there is a possibility of new classes later, I want to make the class initialization and method call generic. Please let me know the best way to achieve it. thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Look into *factory pattern*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a proper way to do it (without generics):

```
public interface ICommon {
   public void add();
}
```

then `Class1,Class2,Class3`,... should implement `ICommon` interface.

With that I recommend you to create a ClassFactory like this:

```
public class ClassFactory {

public static ICommon getInstance() {
... //do here whatever it takes to create a concrete instance of ICommon
}
```

and finally, it would look like this:

```
ICommon someClass = ClassFactory.getInstance();
someClass.add();
```

}

**EDIT:**

Instead of using a switch statement you could add this to your `ClassFactory`:

```
public class ClassFactory {

    private static HashMap<String, String> mClassMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void registerClass(Class<?> clazz, String tag) {
        String name = clazz.getName();
        mClassMapping.put(tag, name);
    }

    public static ICommon getInstance(String tag) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String className = mClassMapping.get(tag);

        if  (null == className) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(String.format("There is no class registered for tag: %s", tag));
        }

        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className);

        return (ICommon)aClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Finally you could do this:
At some starting point register your classes:

```
ClassFactory.registerClass(Class1.class, "c1");
ClassFactory.registerClass(Class2.class, "c2");
...
```

Then get an instance like this:

```
String tag = ...//get tag associated to the class somehow; 

ICommon classInstance = ClassFactory.getInstance(tag);   //i.e tag == "c1"
classInstance.add();
```

Comment: In getInstance(){} method, again i need to put some switch case or if else block to decide which class to initialize and return ?

Comment: @user1849139: The logic for creating a concrete instance of ICommon, certainly depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

@user1849139

1) public interface genaricInterface{
public void commonMethod();
}

2)implement above interface to your class and override the method

3)public Class class1 implements genaricInterface{
public void commonMethod(){
//write your logic here for class1 
}
}

4)Like above class you can implement to n-number of classes in java after that

5)create instance like genaricInterface gi = new class1();

6)call method gi.commonMethod();